# google mobile tracking api

Tags: php, api, google-api

We are doing call taxi business with around 100 drivers.

I want to track these 100 drivers but I am not ready to go for GPRS and any other costly works so I want to track these people using their mobile.

That is, I have all these driver's mobile numbers.  Is there a way to find his/her present location using any google API?

Please tell me Google API for tracking mobile.

Comment: Hi , i make my quyestion very simple,,,

what is ht URL  FOR Google mobile tracking api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tracking a mobile phone, without any special application running on the phone, and without making a data (GPRS) connection is not possibly for normal members of the public. (It is technically possible, but is only able to be done by mobile carriers and even then, only when handling requests from law enforcement authorities). All those bits you see in the movies where they trace a handset are works of fiction.

The only way you could track mobile handsets would involve them reporting their location through GPRS/EDGE or some other cellular data service.

An adaptation of [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/latitude/intro.html) may be possible, but, again, would require all your drivers installing the software, providing permission for you to see their location updates and then ongoing data costs to connect to the Latitude servers and update their locations.

There are others out there who can provide transponders which you can install into your vehicles which would do all of this for you, but, of course, they would charge a premium for that.

Comment: Simply put, what you want cannot be done for free, without the phone-owner's permission and without utilising the GPRS/mobile data service.